# Blender will crash when i use unwrap script

Tags: python

I want to use a script to add lightmap uv for all object in scene.

```
import bpy  
context = bpy.context
#objects = bpy.context.scene.objects 
objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
 
def AddUV(mesh):
        lm = mesh.uv_layers.new(name='lm')
        lm.active = True
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="SELECT")
        bpy.ops.uv.lightmap_pack()
#           bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66, island_margin = 0.02)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        lm.active = True

for obj in objects : 
    if obj.type == 'MESH':   
       context.view_layer.objects.active = obj 
       obj.select_set(state=True)
       mesh = obj.data   
       if len(mesh.uv_layers) < 2: 
           AddUV(mesh)
```

when i select multi objects and click execute, the blender may crash

Comment: Have you try to print some data regarding the process ? How many objects do you have in your selection ?

Comment: Thanks for reply!
It seems to be because blender gets stuck in the unwrapping process and if a second model starts the unwrapping process it crashes.
Selecting 2-3 objects is prone to crashing.
Using an empty item and clicking on the script several times in a row also crashes.
Is there any way to make the cyclic process where one model finishes unwrapping before starting another

Comment: Can you provide more info about "if a second model starts the unwrapping process crash" please ? Can you share a file ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tvRVNLCX41Ie532NcfsmXKxYsyfTNGAL/view?usp=sharing
open this file and select all object in scene, then run the python script, my blender 3.3.1 will crash.

Comment: Good news,
change this code then the blender work fine, not crash any more.
`def AddUV(mesh):
        lm = mesh.uv_layers.new(name='lm')
        lm.active = True
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="SELECT")
        bpy.ops.uv.lightmap_pack()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        lm.active = False`